# Automatic object append

Tags: php, sql

I created a class which generates queries based on arguments I feed it via PHP object chaining. Select, insert, update and delete all define `$this->query` so nothing is left over from previous calls.

Here is an example, keeping in mind that `where()` might be succeeded by `order()`, `limit()`, etc.

```
$tQuery->select('id', 'users')
       ->where('email', '=', $email)
       ->end();
```

All `end()` does is append a `;` to the SQL statement and returns it as a string, so it seems a bit intrusive using it in every single call.

```
public function end()
{
    $this->query .= ';';

    return $this->query;
}
```

Is there a way (magic method or otherwise) I can automatically do this each time I call the class so I don't require this method every time?

```
$tQuery->select('id', 'users')
       ->where('email', '=', $email);
```

i.e. "You're not asking me for any more methods, I'll just return what I have with a `;` at the end"

Comment: May I ask why the `;` is necessary in the first place?

Comment: It's not, I put that in there as a visual indicator that the method was called because it's compatible with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the result of end() is used by some pdo to execute the final query. This means, you need a string-presentation of your query-object in the end. Here, php's type-casting may come in handy. There is a magic method available for objects when using them as string, [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Consider this example:

```
<?php
echo $tQuery->select('id', 'users')
       ->where('email', '=', $email)
       ->end();
```

Now, add a __toString() method to your class:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->end();
}
```

And you may rewrite the above to

```
<?php
echo $tQuery->select('id', 'users')
       ->where('email', '=', $email);
```

This works for any object that is used in a string-context, e.g. this also triggers __toString():

```
<?php
$sqlString = (string)$tQuery->select('id', 'users')
    ->where('email', '=', $email);
```

Comment: It's hard to search the docs for something you don't know the name of, but this was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.